# Why are my ActionBar's tabs disappearing?

Tags: android, tabs

My application is built off of the Navigation Drawer template and in one of my items fragment's, I'm trying to use tabbed navigation. I am attempting to get the tab bar to display directly under the ActionBar.

I see my tab bar for about 0.5 seconds and then it disappears. Not only that, it appears that the two tabs are repeating to fill the tab bar's width.

Relavent code:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class LibraryFragment extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_library, container, false);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab firstTab = actionBar.newTab();
        firstTab.setText("Tab 1");
        firstTab.setTabListener(this);
        actionBar.addTab(firstTab);

        ActionBar.Tab secondTab = actionBar.newTab();
        secondTab.setText("Tab 2");
        secondTab.setTabListener(this);
        actionBar.addTab(secondTab);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        // Do nothing for now.
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {

    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to `invalidateMenuOptions()` being called on my activity. There is boilerplate code in the Navigation Drawer template that was calling this.